# Reading File in actionPerformed method, Taking Answer from JTextArea, and find the right world/answer

Tags: java

I asked a question similar to this, but it didn't really solve the problem that I am having.

Questions:

1. How do I get the text in the JTextArea, to be called into the actionPerformed method, so that it can go through the file and search for that specific word?
2. The file that I have is not opening...Specifically it is going straight to "File Cannot Open" part of the "try" statement. I am using a scanner file to search for the file to see if what they wrote is correct. How do I fix this?

What the program is suppose to do:

What I am trying to achieve with this program is that when the use presses a button on the "game page" of the program, it takes them to a separate page that displays a question. Now the following part of the program is the question frames. It displays a label, and that works. It displays the JTextFile, but what isn't working is its not taking the JTextArea words and searching the file that I have made. After they have entered their answer and pushed the button, is suppose to make a new JLabel and display in the math100() methods frame.

Here is what I have so far coding wise:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        if(event.getActionCommand().equals("Answer M 100"))
        {
            try
            {
                String path = "C:\\Users\\Nathan\\Desktop\\answers_file.txt";
                File answersFile = new File(path);
                Scanner input = new Scanner(answersFile);
                System.out.println(answersFile.getAbsolutePath());
                if(input.hasNext("1,000,000"))
                {
                    System.out.println("This answer is correct!");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("This answer is incorrect.");
                }
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("File cannot load.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void math100()
    {
        JFrame m100Frame = new JFrame("100 Point Math Question");
        m100Frame.setSize(350,350);
        m100Frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        m100Frame.setContentPane(pane);

        JLabel question = new JLabel("<html><p><div WIDTH = 320><center>Round 1,291,293 to the nearest thousands, and round 8.472 to the nearest hundredth.</p><p>Put answers in box below, and have the word 'and' between the two answers.</center></width></div></html>");

        JTextArea answerArea = new JTextArea("",10,25);

        JButton answerQuestion = new JButton("Answer M 100");
        answerQuestion.addActionListener(new allQuestions());

        pane.add(question);
        pane.add(answerArea);
        pane.add(answerQuestion);

        m100Frame.setVisible(true);
        m100Frame.toFront();
    }
```

I looked at the Stack Trace for this part of the program, and the only part that is seems to not be working is:

at allQuestions.actionPerformed(allQuestions.java:16)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The "only" part not working is your whole method. I don't see why you try to use it this way. However.

Try this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource().equals(yourButton)) {
        try {
            String path = "C:\\Users\\Nathan\\Desktop\\answers_file.txt";
            File file = new File(path);
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
            while (input.hasNext()){
                //datatype you need?! I don't know what your .txt file contains.
                String nextToken = input.next(); //a token is a for example a digit or a word. They will be splitted by a space from each other normally.
                //alternatively you get a line
                //String nextLine = input.nextLine();
                String text = yourTextArea.getText();
                if (text.equals(nextToken)) { //alternatively "nextLine"
                    System.out.println("The answer is correct");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("The answer is right");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

To clarify this a bit: `e.getSource().equals(yourButton)` compares if the source of the triggered event is your button you pushed before. If yes: the program should read the file and compare it token by token - or line by line - the file with the text you got in your TextArea.

Comment: Yeah, I mean if there was a simpler way to do what I am trying to do, then it would make my life easier. Talking about the datatype, I'm going to have like answers to questions in this file, so it will be a mix of like numbers and words...I mean. I could use either "int" for whole numbers and string for the words, I believe.

Comment: As well, "String text = yourTextArea.getText();" I have multiple text areas for each of the methods I am using...And right now, when I put my text area there, it says it cannot find it "cannot find symbol - variable 'thetextarea'...how do I fix that? @X-Fate